# Java EE Webservice - How to save a json without a database

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, postman

I have a REST service with a simple get and post method in Java EE. The post method saves the recieved json in a file using Gson and FileWriter. On my local system the file is saved in C:\Users...\Documents\Glassfish Domains\Domain\config. The Get method reads this file and gives out the json.

When I test this on my local system using Postman, everything works fine, but when I deploy the project on a Ubuntu Server vm with Glassfish installed, I am able to connect but I get a http 500 Internal Server Error Code. I managed to find out, that the errors are thrown, when the FileReader/FileWriter tries to do stuff. I suppose that it is restricted to access this directory on a real glassfish instance.

So my question is, if there is a file path where I am allowed to write a file and read it afterwards. This file has to stay there (at least during the applicationr runs) and has to be the same for every request (A scheduler writes some stuff into the file every 24 hours). If anyone has a simple alternative how to save the json in Java EE without an extra database instance, that would be helpful, too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server then you can create a directory using the glassfish server user. Configure this path in some property file in your application and then use this property for reading and writing the file. This way you can configure different directory paths in different environments.